# asp.net mvc order items based on parameters in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to order some products based on prices. What are the parameters I pass to my action and how do I use it in sorting from an `IQueryable<Product>`?

For eg. this is what I currently have:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int page =0, int cat = 0, int subCat =0)
    {
        var products = productService.GetAllProducts();

        ProductListViewModel model = new ProductListViewModel();

        if (cat > 0)
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.SubCategory.CategoryId == cat);
        }
        if (subCat > 0)
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.SubCategory.SubCategoryId == subCat);
        }

        products = products.OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate);

        model.PagedProducts = products.ToPagedList(page, 15);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: If you just want to order by price, there shouldn't be anything that needs to be passed in the action--are you trying to filter down to a subset of products based on some parameter?

Comment: I have 2 urls on my page, one that says sort by highest price and the other for lowest price first.

Answer (score 2):

You may checkout the [following article](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 1):

You may pass any variable you want. An int should be enough but you may also use a string.

```
public ActionResult Index(int page =0, int cat = 0, int subCat =0, int order = 0)
{
    var products = productService.GetAllProducts();

    ProductListViewModel model = new ProductListViewModel();

    if (cat > 0)
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.SubCategory.CategoryId == cat);
    }
    if (subCat > 0)
    {
        products = products.Where(p => p.SubCategory.SubCategoryId == subCat);
    }

    switch(order)
    {
       case 0:
           products = products.OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate);  
           break;
       case 1:
           products = products.OrderBy(p => p.Price);
           break;
    }

    model.PagedProducts = products.ToPagedList(page, 15);
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
products = products.OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate);
```

with

```
products = products.OrderBy(p => p.Price);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `bool` flag that you pass in then you can use it to toggle the sort:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page, int cat, int subCat, int order, bool isAscending)
{
    var products = productService.GetAllProducts();

    if (isAscending)
        products = products.OrderBy(prod => prod.Price); 
    else
        products = products.OrderByDescending(prod => prod.Price);

    // Other code...
}
```